# How to add a timer in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have developed a page that shows different status of the order:
Expected delivery
Delivered.

I need to add a timer ( with mints) next to the Expected Delivery Status.

I have tried to add a timer but i could not. I did not know the right code for it.

```
<xsl:choose >
    <xsl:when test="remarksairside='Expected'">
        <text color="#32CD32" bold="true">
            <text>Expecting Delivery in
</text>

  <!---      the timer code -->

        </text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <text>
            <xsl:value-of select="status" />
        </text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Now, the code shows only the status without the timer. Could you please assist?

Comment: What exactly is "the timer code"? Please post an example that will enable us to reproduce your problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k I meant any function or a statement to show a timer or a countdown timer ( Delivery time in 10 mins) then ( Delivery time in 09 mins).

Comment: I am afraid that's too broad a question. Start by finding out what "function or statement to show a timer" you want to use. IOW, what should your resulting HTML(?) code look like. Then ask how to write XSLT to produce that code from your XML.